# Magento 1.9 category import and export

Tags: magento-1.9, import, export

We have to Export and Import categories in magento 1.9.
Please help me out how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are so many paid extensions for this. You may check magento marketplace for paid extensions. However if you are looking to it without any extension what you can do it just export the product to csv from one magento where you want to export the category and in the magento where you want to import the categories just import the exported product csv. All the categories will be created and you may delete the product if you dont want them to be in your magento.

Comment: ok Thanks for the response, We have huge number of category ids changes.

Comment: In that case you may give this  a try https://github.com/quafzi/magento-category-migration/blob/master/exportCategories.php
However i have not used this  and this is not a magento extension

Comment: Ok @saif i will try and get back.

Comment: Warning: require_once(abstract.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /exportCategories.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'abstract.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in/exportCategories.php on line 2

Comment: We are facing above issues, while run it in magento root folder.